# What are the touchpad requirements to enable at the swipe the switch apps gestures on windows 8

Tags: windows-8, synaptics-touchpad

Is there a specific make, driver, or version of touchpad that's necessary? I have a 2 year old hp dm3 with a 2 finger multitouch alps touchpad and app switching by swiping from left to right does not work in the latest windows 8 release preview. Yet, MS has enabled this feature in the release preview and gestures like semantic zoom do work. Any idea?